# Generating a sequence using itertools.counter

Tags: python, count, python-itertools

Can anyone please explain, why I'm getting error when used counter  without map? As I saw `itertools.count(1)` returns a `count(1)` object.

```
>>> "{:02}".format(itertools.count(1))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: non-empty format string passed to object.__format__

>>> map("{:02}".format, itertools.count(1))
<map object at 0x7f6d514671d0>

>>> counter = map("{:02}".format, itertools.count(1))
>>> next(counter)
'01'
>>> next(counter)
'02'...
```

Comment: What is unclear from the message? You're passing a non-empty format string (`'02' != ''`) to `object.__format__` (the count object doesn't implement that method so it calls the inherited version).

Comment: The first snippet calls `format` on the counter. The other snippets call `format` on the numbers returned by the counter. They're completely different. This is like saying "I have a box of chocolates. If I try to eat the box, it doesn't work. But if I take the chocolates out of the box, I can eat them just fine".

Comment: @Rawing - Thanks, This is what I'm looking for.  `itertools.count(1)` is returning an object. how does map is getting a number? like how can I take chocolate out of my closed box without opening it ? ( if I understood it correctly)  Can you please elaborate it more

Comment: `map` uses the [iterator protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types) to get values out of an iterable, and `itertools.count` is an iterable.

Comment: @Rawing - Oh, Okay so the line is - `next(itertools.count(1))` . Thanks, got it now. You may update it as an answer. I will accept it.